# Matplotlib animation failure due to NoneType Error?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, math

I am working on a program to allow visualization of electrical fields, and I want to have the graph update based on a list of charges (location, charge etc.) The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/BooleanDesign/Electrical-Field-Toolkit/blob/master/app.py), but due to it being close to 300 lines of mostly physics and math, i've decided to ommit most of the code to make the issue much clearer.

I have defined the animation below to animate the intended graph (again, the ins and outs of the functions inside of animate() are quite convoluted, but can be found in the link).

```
def animate():
"""
This function animates the graph
:param i:
:return:
"""
inputs = get_inputs(charges,resolution)
create_graph(inputs[0],inputs[1])

charges = []
resolution = 50
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animate(), interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, after running the program, I recieve the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 283, in resize
    self.show()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 354, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 474, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 62, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1165, in draw
    self.canvas.draw_event(renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1809, in draw_event
    self.callbacks.process(s, event)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 563, in process
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 430, in __call__
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 661, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1221, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1243, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

However, none of these errors actually relate directly to a line in my program, so I am quite lost on any solutions. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your indentation is correct. In general, only if a [mcve] is given one may solve such issue unabmbiguously.

Comment: The problem is that you should be passing a callback function rather than _calling_ the callback function. In the latter case you're calling the callback once on creation of the `FuncAnimation`, and `None` gets passed which is the result of `animate()`. So you need to remove the parentheses from after `animate()` in your call to `FuncAnimation`.